# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mxnet.contrib.amp' When importing gluonnlp

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mxnet, gluon

I have the following versions of `mxnet==1.4.0` and `gluonnlp==0.9.1` installed using pip.

However when I run the following code`import gluonnlp as nlp` it yields the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mxnet.contrib.amp'
```

So I try to manually import the missing module using

```
from mxnet.contrib import amp
import gluonnlp as nlp
```

which also yields an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'amp' from 'mxnet.contrib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mxnet/contrib/__init__.py)
```

I've been running the code on Colab. Is there a possible workaround for this issue?

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used these libraries but in [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/17913#issuecomment-660498934) github issue they say:

> AMP was introduced in MXNet 1.5. Could you try that version (or newer)?

So I think that the problem is there.

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I found that too, that does solve the issue but `MXNet 1.5` is incompatible with the gluonnlp version I'm using